# Fading a vertical line in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I thought this would be an easy problem, but I cannot find anything on this online.

So, I want a vertical line that "fades out". This is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,1) -- (1,1);
        \draw [path fading=south,fit fading=false](1,1) -- (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? I also tried it with gradients, i.e. defining `top color=black` and `bottom color=white`, but that also did not work.

Comment: Remove `fit fading=false`. Then it works.